# Why do NEBNext indexing primers have sequence between the p5 oligo and index?

Tags: phylogenetics, illumina, adapter, pcr, library

[In a previous post](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/why-do-neb-adapters-have-non-complementary-sequence) I asked **Why do NEB adapters have non-complementary sequence?**

Since then, I realized that there is some other sequence in the p5 indexing primer, as well as in the p7 indexing primer.

Here is a diagram of the NEBNext protocol. The parts that I am confused about are in step 5.

[image: NEBNext protocol]

1. My first question is about the p5 index. Why is there a sequence `5'GATCTACAC 3'` between the p5 flowcell oligo and the index?

[image]

2. My second question is about both indices. Why is there no gap between the p7 index and the flowcell annealing oligo?

[image]

For reference, I fetched these indexing primer sequences from [NEB on page 18 and 19 of NEBNext Multiplex Oligos for Illumina instruction manual](https://www.neb.com/-/media/catalog/datacards-or-manuals/manuale7780.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1: The additional sequences is needed because that is complimentary to the P5 sequence anchored to the flow cell. It is also the site for priming the Index 2 read on a MiSeq. The additional sequence is also needed for the read 1 primer in the cartridge to anneal to the correct place for the molecules.

Question 2: The "GT" sequence you're referring to is necessary for the Index 1 and Read 2 primer to anneal to the correct place.

[image]